# Incorrect Function error using mmap with a PhysicalDrive

Tags: python, mmap

I'm trying to load a hard drive and rather than load chunks into memory I thought I'd give mmap a go but it doesn't work with physical drives.

```
file = open("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE4", "r+")

data = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0)

print(data[0:10])
```

I expected the first 10 bytes from the file but instead, I get:

```
OSError: [WinError 1] Incorrect function
```

Comment: I'm running into exactly the same problem: windows 10, trying to mmap a physical drive. Getting the same error. Have you by chance figured out what was happening?